# Merging every 2 rows of a MySQL database table in a single row

Tags: mysql, database, merge, talend

I have a database table that contains person's fingerprints (`template` column here), each person can introduce 2 fingers, so the same person must have 2 records.
Here is the table :

[image]

Person with ID '275' have 2 records, each for a single finger.
Now I am using Talend to create a table so I can merge every two fingerprints in a single one, I mean row n°37 and 38 will be in single row and `template` column will be concatenated to have only one `person_id`

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: How to merge every 2 fingerprints for a single person into one row ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (ids, person_id_integer) 
SELECT CONCAT(finger1.id, "|", finger2.id), finger1.person_id_integer
FROM oldtable finger1, oldtable finger2
where finger1.person_id_integer = finger2.person_id_integer
and finger1.id <> finger2.id
```

Of course, depnds on how you want to store the new data

:)

Comment: Thank you @Enrique for your solution, actually I found an other work around for that and it works, I'll post it as a response so whenever someone need it can find it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution : 
[image]

I added the same table twice as an input and output like shown in this photo and first fetched it with this query :

```
select FP_ID, FP_DEVICE, group_concat(FP_FINGER_PRINT SEPARATOR ''),FP_EMPLOYEE_ID
from t_finger_print GROUP BY FP_EMPLOYEE_ID;
```